# Django Form looping through form fields but display 1 of each field in html row

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a form which dynamically creates a number of fields based on the number of a variable in my HTML I then loop through the form to display the fields but I need to be like so:

row 1 = "Field 1, Field 2"

instead it is like:

row 1 = "Field 1, Field 1"
row 2 = "Field 2, Field 2"

Form Code:

class AttendingForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Attending
    fields = ('name', 'type')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ticket_count = kwargs.pop('count')
    super(AttendingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for i in range(1, self.count):
        self.fields['%d name' % i] = forms.CharField()
        self.fields['%d type' % i] = forms.ChoiceField()
```

HTML Code Snippet:

```
    <form method="post">
    <section>
        <h1>Manage Attendees</h1>
        <div class="content-section">
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="visitor_name">Name
                        {{ field }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="visitor_name">Type</label>
                        {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button button-black">
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
    </form
```

Comment: Wrong solution - and that's not the only things that is not going to work as expected. You want a `formset` instead (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way to do this without adding a property to your form. In your `__init__()` method, at the end, add a new list of dicts:

```
self.ordered_fields = [{
    'name': self.fields['%d name' % i],
    'type': self.fields['%d type' % i]} for i in range(1, self.count)]
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for item in form.ordered_fields %}
    Name: {{ item.name }}
    Type: {{ item.type }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: Don't use spaces in your field names, that might cause issues in your submitted data. Use `'%d-type'` instead of `'%d type'`.

Comment: I'm just about to post an answer I've used to get around it however I don't know what issues it may cause later on with submitting the form so i may give yours ago as well.

Comment: yes note you shouldn't use spaces in the field names. Instead of `%d name` use `%d-name` or `%d_name`

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted the form to a forms.Fom and set the label of each name field, then set some if statements in the html to order correctly.

Form Code:

```
class AttendingForm(forms.Form):
    # class Meta:
    #     model = Attending
    #     fields = ('attendee_name', 'booking_type')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ticket_count = kwargs.pop('count')
        super(AttendingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in range(1, self.count):
            self.fields['%d name' % i]= forms.CharField(label="attendee_name")
            self.fields['%d type' % i] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(
                ('-------', '-------'),
                ('adult', 'Adult'),
                ('child', 'Child'),
            ))
```

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post">
<section>
            <h1>Manage Attendees</h1>
            <div class="content-section">
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field.label == 'attendee_name' %}
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <label for="visitor_name">Name</label>
                            {{ field }}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <label for="visitor_name">Type</label>
                            {{ field }}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button button-black">
                </div>

            </div>

        </section>
        </form>
```

Comment: That's a bit hacky. The value 'attendee_name' is a "magic value", if you change some python code, your template breaks. Also note that `for="visitor_name"` is wrong for one of the labels. You can use `{{ field.tag_for_label }}` to display the correct label tag without having to rely on specific field ids/names etc...